# "...huddle up..."

Tags: phrase-usage

> A few of the hostages have huddled up...
>
> Hostage: *We need to get out of here. What do we do?*

1. Have I used "huddle up" naturally in the sentence?
2. Will any native speaker know what "huddle up" means?
3. Is there something that might be more natural to use instead in this context? What about "put their heads together"?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, not really.
2. Yes.
3. Yes. *Huddled up* usually refers to sports, so it's not the best choice here. *Huddled together* or *drawn together* or *gathered together* or something like that is more natural.

Comment: Sorry, but that statement is not true. huddle with or without up  means to group together and existed long before any sport used it.

Comment: SIgh. I said that "huddled up" USUALLY (COMMONLY, ORDINARILY) refers to sports. That's my experience. Note that I did not speak about origins. I spoke ONLY about contemporary usage and what is going to sound good in that context.

Comment: The puppies were all **huddled up** in a corner.

Comment: That's unusual to my ears, sorry. I don't think of puppies huddling. My answer stands. (Really, you ought to know this by now but I guess you're having fun excavating answers from February for some reason...bored?)

Comment: "I also wanted us to have fun, huddled up together. This would be Sophie’s first live, howling hurricane and I knew she’d always remember it". https://www.nytimes.com/2008/09/18/garden/18staying.html From: ludwig.guru